# Check URL contains Text then do .click()

Tags: jquery, url, click

I can't get this working. I'm not the best and don't know whether this code makes sense. I tried to check whether the URL contains this text if yes do a `.click()`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    if (window.location.href.indexOf("Peripherie") > -1) {

        $(".page-id-13127 .toggle_managed .nav .nav-tabs li:nth-child(5) a").click();
    }

});
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in your browser console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try firing the click from the HTML element not the jQuery object.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    if (window.location.href.indexOf("Peripherie") > -1) {

        $(".page-id-13127 .toggle_managed .nav .nav-tabs li:nth-child(5) a")[0].click();
    }

});
```

`HTMLElement.click()` **Demo here...**
http://jsfiddle.net/b9x0ykxb/

`jQuery.click()` **Demo Here...**
http://jsfiddle.net/b9x0ykxb/1/